# jquery autocomplete 'Disable' show all terms

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Hey could someone guide me out of this problem....
I successfully created the jquery autocomplete function , but my problem is that autocomplete suggestions shows all the available labels . Autocomplete is showing the results which are not even matching the search term . I mean it showing all available label . Is their any solution to show only matching labels. here is the java function.
Any help will be gladly appreciated . Thank You

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#search-title").autocomplete({
     source: function ( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
           url: "availabletags.json",
           dataType: "json",
           data: {
                    term: request.term      
           },
           success: function (data) {
              response( $.map( data.stuff, function ( item ) {
                 return {
                    label: item.label,
                    value: item.value
              };
           }));
        }
        });
        },
       minLength: 2,

       select: function (event, ui) {
       $(event.target).val(ui.item.label);
       window.location = ui.item.value;
       return false;
     }
   });
});
```

EDIT : - Here is the Json File

```
    {"stuff":[ {"label" : "Dragon", "value" : "eg.com"}  , 
     {"label" : "testing", "value" : "eg2.com"}]}
```

Successful Edited Code

```
      <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search-title").autocomplete({
    source: function ( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "availabletags.json",

       dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
    var sData = data.stuff.filter(function(v) { 
      var re = new RegExp( request.term, "i" );
    return re.test( v.label );

    });
    response( $.map( sData, function ( item ) {
                return {
                    label: item.label,
      value: item.value
                };
            }));
        }
       });
      },
      minLength: 2,
      focus: function (event, ui) {
      this.value = ui.item.label;
       event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default focus behavior.
      },

        select: function (event, ui) {
          $(event.target).val(ui.item.label);
         window.location = ui.item.value;
         return false;
         }
         });
         });
         </script>
```

Comment: You're not using the user's input to filter what is returned; can you post the structure of your JSON.

Comment: hey Json File now added, could you please guide , it would be very helpful

Comment: See answer below ... let us know if you have any questions.

Comment: Did the changes Bro .. But not Working :( 
now the autocomplete is not showing any suggestions....

Comment: Can you confirm you have made the exact changes I suggested? Can you create a jsfiddle and show the updated code or provide a link to your site.

Comment: I created a test page.....here is the link friend
http://mp3visa.com/autocomp/auto.html
please guide really finding this hard

Comment: It should be `return v.value.indexOf.......`, and you do not need the `data` attribute in the ajax call. It's just not useful.

Comment: I did that change bro but no effect....could you make jsfiddle it would be very helpful bro..thank you

Comment: It's working fine. It appears you're searching by label ... if you type `site ...` it will show results of search by value. To have code search by label just change it to: `return v.label.indexOf....`

Comment: Thanks bro....I made the change....but please check ..If I searched for dragon its not showing results

Comment: Just a small bug bro...when I use arrow keys its showing the site url..any help for that??..really thank you

Comment: hey got that fixed using a focus function...I have updated all the edited code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the change you want to make:

```
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var sData = data.stuff.filter(function(v) { 
            return v.value.indexOf( request.term ) > -1; 
        });
        response( $.map( sData, function ( item ) {
```

This search will be done by `value`. To search by `label`, in other words for the user's input to be compared to the label in your JSON use the following instead:

```
return v.label.indexOf( ........
```

**UPDATE**

To make your search case insensitive, use the following:

```
var re = new RegExp( request.term, "i" );
return re.test( v.label );
```

instead of `return v.value.indexOf( request.term ) > -1;`